# getting undefined array inside click function inside for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to this so i guess i'm missing something simple. The foor loop works fine but inside it i get an undefined variable

```
 var categories_info = ["historia","excelencia","arte","social","instalaciones","padres","familia"];
for ( var i = 0; i < categories_info.length; i++) {
  $("#showMe-"+categories_info[i]).click(function(){
    $(".info."+categories_info.[i]).addClass("info-show");
    console.log(".info."+categories_info[i]); //debug is undefinded
  });
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a closure like

```
var categories_info = ["historia", "excelencia", "arte", "social", "instalaciones", "padres", "familia"];
for (var i = 0; i < categories_info.length; i++) {
    (function(i) {
        $("#showMe-" + categories_info[i]).click(function() {
            $(".info." + categories_info[i]).addClass("info-show");
            console.log(".info." + categories_info[i]); 
        });
    })(i);
};
```

This method is known as an [IIFE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Basically, what was happening is the variable `i` was unavailable to the callback when the actual click happened.

However, by passing `i` in a self-executing anonymous function, you have created a *closure* which will preserve `i` and is accessible to the click handler.

Comment: Thanks! i didn't know about this, thank you for the info about the method. I see in console.log what I expected but i'm getting `Unexpected token [` on this line `$(".info." + categories_info.[i]).addClass("info-show");` wich seems really odd

Comment: @ShairNash, it was a syntax error with an extra `.`. Try my updated answer and let me know if it still doesnt work

Comment: I see the dot now! how did I miss it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Use a closure. Change:

```
$("#showMe-"+categories_info[i]).click(function(){
    $(".info."+categories_info.[i]).addClass("info-show");
    console.log(".info."+categories_info[i]); //debug is undefinded
});
```

To:

```
(function( i ) {
    $("#showMe-"+categories_info[i]).click(function(){
        $(".info."+categories_info.[i]).addClass("info-show");
        console.log(".info."+categories_info[i]);
    });
})( i );
```